# Can't dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 in Ryzen 3600

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 19.04

My system is Ryzen 3600 with an Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard which I recently purchased. I have Windows 10 installed, and I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu along with it, but I could not boot Ubuntu from the USB drive. I have turned off fast boot from the BIOS and Secure Boot is in setup mode. These are the photos of the error.

This error appears first.

[image: This error appears first]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

And then this.

[image: And then this]

I have no idea why this error occurs or how can I solve them. I've tried with `nomodeset` (though I don't know what this is) before booting, but it still occurs.

Comment: You probably need UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. AMD UEFI/BIOS update for Ryzen 3000 series
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ryzen-3000-BIOS-Update-Good
ASUS ROG CROSSHAIR VIII HERO WiFi - update supports Ubuntu 19.04  The nomodeset boot parameter is normally for nVidia boot of install & first boot or until nVidia driver installed.

Comment: @oldfred thanks a lot. After updating the BIOS everything works fine.