# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on Asus ROG Strix

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, uefi, usb-installation

BIOS version: 305.

In Boot Menu I see: The system cannot find any bootable devices.

```
Advanced mode -> Sata configuration: AHCI
Security -> Secure Boot Control: Disabled
Boot -> Fast Boot: Enabled
```

Now about Boot, I have only 3 options there:

```
Fast Boot: Enabled
Boot Option Priorities (not clickable)
Delete Boot Option
```

There is no CSM option like I saw across the internet.
The problem is not installation, but I cannot boot from usb or anything at all. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I would turn fast boot off. That assumes you have no hardware or operarating systems changes and boots using last scan of system. Boot is often so fast you have no time to press any key. I would also make sure you have latest UEFI,  even if new system. You may have to redo settings as UEFI update often resets to defaults. You also should have an UEFI setting for USB, either allow USB port or full USB support or something similar. You may not want CSM, but UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679

Comment: what rog strix board do you have z370, z390 or older as there are diffrent bios for older boards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved the issue.
The problem was my executable USB was in NTFS format, but FAT32 only is supported.

So the solution was to create executable USB with Windows installer in FAT32, after that I saw my USB as boot option.