# Cannot install/boot Ubuntu from multiple LiveUSBs

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, usb, live-usb

I am experiencing weird behavior on a desktop PC with an [ASUS X570-F ROG-strix gaming motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-Strix-X570-F-Gaming/specifications/) with the [AMD Ryzen 9 3900X](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900x) (which has no integrated graphics).

I've recently upgraded my hardware, and when I try to boot from an USB-stick which previously worked fine, I do get GRUB. When I then select the option "Try Ubuntu", it seems to crash; I get this  (rather uninformative) screen:

[image]

I have already tried numerous solutions, but I am out of ideas. Thing I've tried:

- Different USB sticks. Problem persists.
- Different Ubuntu versions (Version 18.04.4 LTS, Version 19.10). Problem persists

I am using RUFUS to create a bootable .iso file on my USB-stick. When I try these USB-sticks in my laptop, I can use the option to Try Ubuntu. It then loads a live version of Ubuntu.

The specs of my new PC:

```
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X
Gigabyte NVIDIA 2070 RTX
32 GB of 3600 MHz G.Skill RAM
ASUS X570-F ROG-strix gaming motherboard
Samsung 970 Evo plus M.2 SSD 500 GB with windows installed
Samsung 860 Evo 500 GB with nothing on it (Ideally I want to install Ubuntu on this SSD).
```

I am out of ideas! Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The NVIDIA video adapter has lost synchronization with the monitor. Adding the _nomodeset_ parameter to GRUB is the next step towards a solution. You will need to edit the /boot/grub/grub.conf on the new USB flash drive using an editor on another PC.

Comment: Thx! The problem seems to lie in that I did not have CSM-mode enabled on my mainboard. I just enabled it, and now i AM able to boot from the USB-stick. Strange.

Comment: Cheered to early; now the Ubuntu loading screens shows up; However after that my screen turns off. I am able to boot into Ubuntu 19.1, but not into 18.04.4.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware to latest available?  Even if new hardware there may be newer versions. Newest kernel is required. Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679

Comment: I've updated my mainboard BIOS. Still the same result. I am able to select the options in GRUB, but after the typical ubuntu loading screen (https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+loading+screen&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjgz5Oy5eDnAhUMCuwKHaanAb0Q_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1920&bih=973#imgrc=jFAM9ldKdeejCM) my monitors say they have no signal and nothing happens.

Comment: Solved the problem! I tought it had something to do with my display driver. I have one monitor on a HDMI port, and the other on a DPI port on my GPU. When I unplugged one monitor, everything works fine and I am able to install Ubuntu like normal. Upgraded to the latest NVIDIA drivers, and everything is working fine even with two monitors. Fantastic =).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem! I tought it had something to do with my display driver. I have one monitor on a HDMI port, and the other on a DPI port on my GPU. When I unplugged one monitor, everything works fine and I am able to install Ubuntu like normal. Upgraded to the latest NVIDIA drivers, and everything is working fine even with two monitors.

*Footnote: Explanation as to WHY this is happening would be great. I provided this answer so people know what to do when they have a similar problem. That being said, I will not accept it. Once somebody answers this question with a detailed explanation of what exactly is happening here, I will accept that answer.*