# Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 via live USB (Ryzen 5 3600)

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I recently upgraded to a Ryzen 5 3600, Asus Rog Strix B550, 32GB DDR4 3200 Mhz, 2x Samsung EVO Plus 970. My plan is to have Windows 10 on its own m.2 while Ubuntu is on my second m.2. (Windows 10 is already installed) When I boot the live USB to install Ubuntu I am greeted with a screen of errors.

I have tried updating my BIOS to the latest version. I have Fast Boot, CSM and virtualization disabled.

Most of it is AMD-VI errors and then the PC just freezes up. My old build (Ryzen 5 1600) I had no problems dual booting. Does Linux have issues with the new Zen CPUs? I am kind of at a loss here since I really need this up and running asap.

[image]

Comment: If you have `csm` disabled (UEFI enabled) then you need to prepare USB stick in UEFI mode. `Rufus` can do that.

Comment: I should of noted that my usb stick is already in uefi mode.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679

Comment: @oldfred isnt UEFI and SSD firmware the same thing as the bios update? I have the latest BIOS update.

Comment: Yes. But it has not been BIOS since about 2012, but many vendors still call it BIOS. But the "BIOS" update may not have updated SSD firmware. Samsung has firmware updates on its support site.

Comment: @oldfred I updated the firmware for my m.2's. I still get the same errors.

Comment: Some with other brand motherboards, but same AMD chip have needed IOMMU changes. turns out the IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to AMD  boards. And then perhaps this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft" But this user just installed & it worked. Asus tuf gaming x570-plus
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445883

Comment: @oldfred I figured it out! I disabled iommu and it works. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This comment worked for me:

> Some with other brand motherboards, but same AMD chip have needed IOMMU changes. turns out the IOMMU needs to be enabled in the BIOS. This problems seems to be exclusive to AMD boards. And then perhaps this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"