# Unable to boot into Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to boot into Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from a USB stick. The USB device is formatted as FAT32 and I used `balena-etcher-electron` to put Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on it.

The machine is a Threadripper 3970x on ASUS Zenith extreme II. If I press <kbd>F8</kbd> and turn on the PC, I can select the USB device to boot from, but then it fails to boot.

The picture shows the screen where it stops. What's wrong?

[image: failing boot]

Comment: There seems to be a problem with `iommu`. I have no own experience of it, but I found several link, that might be useful for you, when I searched the internet for `ubuntu iommu`

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest firmware available? And if SSD, updated its firmware? What video card/chip? Asus EX-A320M-Gaming Needed UEFI update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2449330 &  Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679
Asus Rog Strix B550 Disable IOMMU
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265397/unable-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-via-live-usb-ryzen-5-3600?noredirect=1#comment2141726_1265397

Comment: Yes, I have a Bios-Flasback with the latest version from the ASUS website

Comment: I have not updated the firmware for the ssd but I dont want to use it here, I want to boot into ubuntu from the USB-device.