# Grub not detected after Kubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kubuntu, windows-10

I have a pc with an MSI B550 Gaming Plus motherboard, with Windows 10 on it.

After trying to install Kubuntu with different ways to partition the SSD (install windows using the whole disc and have Kubuntu resize it, install windows on part of the disc and manually make a new partition for Kubuntu, etc.), none of these seems to install grub2 in a way that is detected.

I've tried boot loader installation to /dev/sda as well as /dev/sda1 (the ESP used by windows), but it does not seem to put grub2 there.

When I run BCDedit in Windows, it only shows the windows boot manager and the windows boot loader.

As the Kubuntu installation completes without errors I assume that grub2 is placed somewhere, but not not where the motherboard setup 'MSI click' can find it.

Is there a way to change this without reinstalling Kubuntu or windows?

EDIT: using a usb flash drive with boot-repair and the advanced option 'backup and rename Windows EFI files' I can boot into grub2, but then the Windows boot option does not do anything, it returns to the menu.

Maybe something is wrong with the menu option? It now reads:

```
setparams 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)'
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint == xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  409C-954a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 409C-954a
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

What I understand of this makes sense. But then there seems to be a choice between moving the Windows files, getting grub2 but no Windows, and using boot-repair without moving the files and not getting grub2?

Comment: Are both installs UEFI? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Is UEFI most current firmware version and if SSD does that have latest firmware? Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679
Asus Rog Strix B550 Disable IOMMU
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265397/unable-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-via-live-usb-ryzen-5-3600?noredirect=1#comment2141726_1265397

Comment: This is the boot report: http://sprunge.us/dffU9B -- so according to the first section something has definitely been put onto /efi but only /efi/Microsoft is found? I'm not sure what /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda4 are -- they were made automatically by windows.

Comment: You have GRUB_TIMEOUT=10, so ten seconds. If you want grub menu to always show you can change GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` you may need to change UEFI settings (not UEFI menu)  to have ubuntu entry as first in boot order and make sure default boot mode is UEFI.

Comment: Boot-Repair looks like it is just reinstalling grub. But you have ubuntu entry in UEFI, and /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP. Not sure why your UEFI should not see another UEFI boot option. What is MSI click. You should have an UEFI key for boot menu. Same key you use to select USB flash drive installer.

Comment: Only 10  years ago we had issues with too many entries. And it was a vendor's UEFI that said filled up when only 50% full. You can have many entries in UEFI, but grub typically overwrites a previous "ubuntu" entry on reinstall. Users can get confused as "ubuntu" UEFI entry used by other official flavors of Ubuntu and also many unofficial flavors based on Ubuntu. Others may have "grub" or name of distribution.

Comment: Thanks! But which of the two cases does this describe: the one that boots to grub2 but Windows does not start, or the one where grub is ignored by the windows bootloader?

Comment: Windows is not designed to be multiBoot capable except for multiple Windows. It does not do other operating systems. Grub will boot other systems, but Windows cannot be hibernated, fast startup on, nor encrypted (bitlocker).

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, there was an option to select grub instead of windows bootloader, it was somewhere else than the boot order. This means I can undo the boot-repair changes and choose windows from grub! If you type your comment as an answer then I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not designed to be multiBoot capable except for multiple Windows.
It does not do other operating systems.

Grub will boot other systems, but Windows cannot be hibernated, fast startup on, nor encrypted (bitlocker).

Both systems have to be in same boot mode or now almost all systems are UEFI, so both systems need to be installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives.

One advantage of UEFI, is that you should always be able to boot from UEFI boot menu. But always have good backups and both an Ubuntu live installer and windows repair/recovery drive to make repairs, if needed.

Comment: Thanks! In the end i would not have needed to do all the boot-repair stuff. I was confused by the UEFI boot order as it listed the main drive as 'windows' only. But there is a separate menu where you can select which boot manager to use (widows or grub). So the Ubuntu install would have worked out of the box with just that...