# Error while trying to install any Linux version (Ubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Solus GNOME, etc.)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, 20.04, crash

I am new to Linux, but I have a lot of knowledge with PCs and Windows 10 /  macOS in general.

Specs:

- Asus ROG strix b450-F
- Ryzen 7 2700x 4.1GHz
- Asus ROG strix GTX 1060 A6G
- HyperX Predator DDR4 32GB 3200MHz (16-17-17-36)

I am trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu Budgie. I have already made an bootable USB stick with Rufus, and I bought a new 256GB HDD just for Linux.

I am able to get into the grub but after I select *Install Ubuntu* it flashes these [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qbyg.jpg) for some seconds and after that the files on the USB stick get checked like it would normally do. My problem is that I can't get into the installation menu because my PC would crash and I get stuck on a black screen.

[image]

I tried:

1. Disabling Fast boot and Secure Boot
2. Using other USB drives
3. Editing something in the grub to `nomodeset`
4. Unplugging every other drive except for the 256GB one

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest version, updated SSD firmware and are using 20.04.1?  Asus ROG Strix B450 E motherboard UEFI update worked
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174679/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-in-ryzen-3600?noredirect=1#comment1960921_1174679

Comment: Yes i did update my UEFI and yes i tried installing 20.04.1.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Edit your question and also show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thank you for the help heynnema! Resetting my extreme Overclock did the job!

Comment: Great news! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

Asus ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING

You have BIOS version xxxx.

The current BIOS is version 3103, from 6/23/2020, and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**overclock**

If your CPU or RAM are overclocked, set them back to default.

**Ryzen vs memory**

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility problems.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

If `memtest` freezes, or has errors, contact me BEFORE trying any troubleshooting on your own.

CPU Support List: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_CPU/

Memory Support List: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_QVL/

User's Manual: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_Manual/