# Error: The attempt to mount a file system failed when trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as main OS

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have been really struggling with installing Ubuntu on my pc and would greatly appreciate any help. This is how the error is occurring. My pc boots up and then I select the "Install Ubuntu" option as I want Ubuntu as my main OS. I then click on the Normal Installation option, then "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and select the appropriate SSD which I want. Below this option I am prompted with "2 partitions will be deleted, use the advanced partitioning tool fro more control", I proceed by clicking "Install Now". Then the installer prompts me with "The following partitions are going to be formatted:
partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ESP
partition #2 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4". Then I click continue and now this is where the issue keeps arising. I have went through this process multiple times and after hitting continue at that step I am met with "The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed. You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu" Now I have ZERO idea what to do and am so scared because my PC is now rendered completely useless. I can't do anything on it! I have an Asus prime Z390 mobo, i9-9900k, and an RTX 2080 Ti gpu. Any advice/help is greatly appreciated! I have an Asus motherboard if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include some details about the computer you’re installing Ubuntu onto? This may allow someone to offer specific solutions 

Comment: Include brand/model system, video card/chip & version & flavor of Ubuntu you are installing. If you have partitions, post this in quesiton: `sudo fdisk -lu`

Comment: @oldfred Yes sorry as you can tell I am a complete noob and was unaware that I should've provided that information.  I have an Asus prime Z390 mobo, i9-9900k, and an RTX 2080 Ti gpu. Cheers!

Comment: @matigo Just edited the question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Similar issues? Asus  Z390 AORUS PRO WIFI 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2470463 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267714/error-while-trying-to-install-any-linux-version-ubuntu-ubuntu-budgie-solus-gn?noredirect=1#comment2146118_1267714